# Why does this sql statement take so long?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am a beginner in Access. I write this SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_LaunchWeeklyPlan
IN 'C:\...\SomeDb.accdb'

SELECT ID, LaunchID, WeekYear, LaunchWeek, LaunchYear, Quantity, true AS IsActive 
FROM tbl_LaunchWeeklyPlan t 
WHERE t.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID 
FROM tbl_LaunchWeeklyPlan 
IN 'C:\...\SomeDb.accdb')
```

It takes about 5 minutes and the tables contain about 15 000 records.

Comment: Do you run this from `MEM_BE_GEU (7_13).accdb`?

Comment: No, I run it from another access db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using an outer join instead. This may execute quicker.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_LaunchWeeklyPlan IN 'C:\...\SomeDb.accdb' 
SELECT ID, LaunchID, WeekYear, LaunchWeek, LaunchYear, Quantity, true AS IsActive FROM tbl_LaunchWeeklyPlan t
LEFT JOIN tbl_LaunchWeeklyPlan IN 'C:\...\SomeDb.accdb' f
ON t.ID = f.ID
WHERE f.ID = null
```

Comment: It is very close, but f.ID IS NULL wouldn't be better?

Comment: Yes sorry, IS NULL is correct syntax. Have you tried running the insert without the condition on it and ignoring errors?

Comment: I tried, actually solved my problem replacing the '=' to IS, thank you.